# Using one circuit's voltage range to control the range of another

Tags: fluid-pump

MAF sensor = MAss airflow sensor, measures the amount of air going in the engine, the engine is "mapped" to translate a MAF voltage into airflow (grams of air per second)

I'm trying to make a circuit that uses my car's MAF sensor's voltage to control a methanol pump. The pump is a 12V pump, and has a max draw of around 10A. The sensor on the other hand has a max voltage of 5v, so 0v = no airflow and 5v = max airflow, or the upper limit of the sensor.

It would be nice if I could translate the voltage from the MAF sensor to control the pump speed, maybe by letting 5v output = max voltage to pump(12v) and so forth.

What is the best way to go about this?

P.S If i can't linearly translate the MAF to scale the pump speed, it would be acceptable if i could use a configured voltage to set an "on" state for the pump whenever the sensor is higher than this Voltage

eg:

```
>3volts = pump on, < 3volts pump off
```

I'm thinking some variable resistor would be in this circuit
but one condition is that it mustn't disturb the voltage that the ECU is seeing

Thanks for allowing me to clarify

Comment: Deleting and then re-asking the same question is seriously frowned upon here.

Comment: Better question this time. But you still can't just expect an answer. At one level, what you want is clear : increase the flow of methanol with increasing air volume. But how much methanol do you really want for each litre of air? And how much menhanol does the pump deliver at each input voltage? And what does 1V or 5V from your MAF sensor represent in litres/secon of air? Once you know all these you can draw a graph of volts out vs volts in - THEN you have a question that can be answered.

Comment: @Brian: Actually the question can be well answered except for the exact mapping, which doesn't really change the topology of the circuit.  However, I don't want to spend time writing a answer only to find this question too gets deleted when he gets a downvote or two, doesn't like what he hears, or something.  We have now lost the history of this question.  It is useful to see what was asked and answered before, and it gives insight into the OP's background and the like.

Comment: +1 Brian. Lots of people here can build the circuit you need, but there's a lot of missing details. I would get the numbers for desired methanol injection rate versus air flow rate - it might not be linear, or there could be an offset where you want it to wait. And the motor might not respond terribly well to just having it's voltage reduced - do you have a datasheet or a part number? All told, we need to know more, and you need to show us that you're making an effort to figure it out.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I'm new here and it was confusing so i deleted it and come again. The posting wasn't in a question form, the guys simply asked me to state it better.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Thanks but don't worry about the exact mapping yet. I have that part covered with nozzle sizing and tuning. Some trial and testing would be needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you break this project into several pieces:

- A DC motor controller that supplies 0-full power from (say) 0-5V in.
- A power supply suitable for the automotive environment
- Signal conditioning and processing that maps the 0-5V to 0-5V out.

You can purchase the first bit and I would suggest you do that, since it will cheaply get you off the ground, and that part can be a bit tricky.

The power supply can be as simple as a 7808 regulator and some transient protection (capacitors, a TVS, a polyfuse).

The signal conditioning would consist of a bit of a filter for the MAF sensor signal, a variable offset (for setting what airflow level the methanol pump should start) and a variable gain (for setting how quickly the methanol pump level increases as the mass airflow increases. This is a linear approximation to whatever is actually optimal.

The latter circuit could consist of a couple op-amps, some panel-mount potentiometers and some resistors and capacitors (perhaps add a bit of circuitry to indicate when the pump is off or running flat out). Or you could insert a microcontroller with ADC and DAC, and whatever kind of human-machine interface you want.

Comment: Nice. The last part probably would be the most difficult as i have no experience with op amps. I currently have a circuit that can show low level and pump status via LED. Also has a failsafe if the liquid runs low to tell the ECU to run low boost.

my biggest concern is how i separate the 5v from the 12v circuit.

Comment: Yes, as I understand it a sudden loss of C3H0H could severely damage the engine. Whether you use op-amps or microcontrollers is a matter of your tools, experience and confidence in learning. Op-amps would be quite easy though, and if you have specific questions they would probably be compact enough for this site. If you get a motor controller that accepts a 0-5V control signal then you just need to create that signal from the 0-5V input (hence the 8V supply and circuitry).

Answer (score 1):

When experimenting with methanol as engine fuel, be aware of its corrosivity in high concentration to aluminium. Methanol, a weak acid, attacks the oxide coating that normally protects the aluminum from corrosion:

6 CH3OH + Al2O3 → 2 Al(OCH3)3 + 3 H2O

The resulting methoxide salts are soluble in methanol, resulting in a clean aluminium surface, which is readily oxidized by dissolved oxygen. Also, the methanol can act as an oxidizer:

6 CH3OH + 2 Al → 2 Al(OCH3)3 + 3 H2

This reciprocal process effectively fuels corrosion until either the metal is eaten away or the concentration of CH3OH is negligible. Concerns with methanol's corrosivity have been addressed by using methanol-compatible materials, and fuel additives that serve as corrosion inhibitors.

The best way to plan the pump controller is:

1. Use a microcontroller such as an Arduino
2. Connect the MAF sensor to an analog input pin. Digitize the voltage in the built-in ADC.
3. Provide for a non-linear mapping from sensor voltage to pump drive - we cannot define this map for you. It will require engine tests at various r.p.m., loads and temperatures , preferably carried out on a dynamometer with a lambda probe in the exhaust to monitor stoichemetry.
4. The pump motor should probably be driven by 12V pulses with the microcontroller continually adjusting their mark-to-space ratio. (This is also true for a continuously rotating motor which would have difficulty starting on a low voltage.)

More useful info at:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methanol#Fuel_for_vehicles
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engine_control_unit

Comment: OK. I like the way you panned this out. I'm aware of the tuning requirement and I'm very able and competent in that area.

I have an arduino, but i'm unsure of how to drive the pump using the 0v-5v output of the arduino.